# yum not updating dependency during install

Tags: centos, redhat, yum, rhel7

I have a situation where `my-software` requires `my-common` via:

```
Requires: my-common >= 1.2.0
```

During `yum update my-software`, `my-common` is not upgraded, and is left at version `0.0.1`.

Why is yum not updating `my-common` -- and the install of `my-software` completes without error, even though the dependency for `my-common` is not resolved?

---

See:

```
# yum deplist my-software
package: my-software.noarch 1.1.0-1637255366
  dependency: /bin/sh
   provider: bash.x86_64 4.2.46-34.el7
  dependency: my-common >= 1.2.0
   provider: my-common.x86_64 1.2.0-1637243847.el7_9
   provider: my-common.noarch 0.0.1-20180703160841.el7
```

Note that yum thinks that `my-common` is resolved by either of:

- `my-common.x86_64 1.2.0-1637243847.el7_9`
- `my-common.noarch 0.0.1-20180703160841.el7`

The latter is already installed. Running `yum update my-common` correctly updates to the `1.2.0` version, and then `my-software` works correctly.

Noting that the timestamp in the latter package is incorrectly formatted and appears "newer" than the first. But the first has the version I'm requiring, so I would have expected the latter to be completely excluded from the list of valid packages.

Comment: bump into the same issue, have you resolved this? Thanks!

Comment: I really don't remember, I probably just installed the package manually and moved on with my life. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is because the inproper `Provides` in spec file of `my-common`.

I encountered the similar problem, and finally I found that, the `Provides` in spec was misconfigured.

For example,

```
# without version
Provides: my-common
```

After this line was removed, **newer** version could be normally updated by `yum install`.

Comment: You removed the entire `Provides: ...` line?

Comment: Yes, let the RPM build tools set the default value. If default value was not expected, you should care about the version value in `Provides`. For example, `Provides: my-common = 0.0.1`.